# When CosmosDb says 10 ms write latency, does it include the time it takes for the write request to reach the cosmosdb server?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

This document on [cosmosdb consistency levels and latency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels#consistency-levels-and-latency) says CosmosDb writes have a latency of 10ms at the 99th percentile. Does this include the time it takes for the write to reach CosmosDB. I suspect not, since if I issue a request far away from my configured azure regions, I don't see how it can take < 10 ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SLA is for the latency involved in performing the operations and returning results. As you mention, it does not include time taken to reach the Cosmos endpoint, which depends on the client's distance.

As indicated in [performance guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips-dotnet-sdk-v3-sql):

> You can get the lowest possible latency by ensuring that the calling
> application is located within the same Azure region as the provisioned
> Azure Cosmos DB endpoint.

In my experience latency <10ms is typical for an app located in the same region as the Cosmos endpoint it works against.